# Permissions in Ext4 Truecrypt Drive

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, external-hdd

I just used the Truecrypt GUI to encrypt my entire USB hard drive (currently /dev/sdb).  I formatted it to ext4.  Now, I can mount it in my home directory with the command

> truecrypt --mount /dev/sdb USB-Device

For some reason I don't have read/write permission.  So my question is: How do I get read/write permission?  Is it a drive-specific issue, or a system issue? It wouldn't surprise me if there was just a group I had to add my user account to.

Additionally, I'm running Arch Linux, but I'm pretty sure that's not entirely relevant.

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to use Truecrypt? Dmcrypt (for whole disk/partition encryption) or Ecryptfs (to encrypt a directory tree belonging to one user) are usually a lot easier to set up under Linux. TC has the advantage of working on Windows and OSX but that's not useful if you put a Linux filesystem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually something along the lines of this for any new filesystem:

```
mount /dev/newthing /mount/point
chown owner:group /mount/point/
chmod 750 /mount/point/
```

(obviously using different values for owner / group / 750 depending on your requirements)

It doesn't matter if newthing is encrypted or not. In the end you have a regular filesystem which follows regular permission rules. If for some reason you don't have permission, unless you opened the crypt container itself in read-only mode, it's a question of `chown`/`chmod`. Nothing special about it.